# Angular 2 Databinding from Observable

Tags: ionic2, angular2-template, ionic3

I have a page which is listening to beacon events. I want to show a popup when the beacon is detected. I have the following code:

home.ts

```
export class HomePage {
  beacon_found: boolean;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public events: Events, public ibeacon: IBeacon) {

    this.ibeacon.requestAlwaysAuthorization();
    let delegate = this.ibeacon.Delegate();

    let region = this.ibeacon.BeaconRegion('ibirapuera','B9407F30-F5F8-466E-AFF9-25556B57FE6D');
    this.ibeacon.startMonitoringForRegion(region)
    .then(
      () => console.log('Native layer recieved the request to monitoring'),
      error => console.error('Native layer failed to begin monitoring: ', error)
    )

    delegate.didStartMonitoringForRegion()
    .subscribe(
      (data) => console.log("Started monitoring beacons", data)
    )

    delegate.didEnterRegion()
    .subscribe(
      (data) => {
        this.beacon_found = true;
      }
    )

    delegate.didExitRegion()
    .subscribe(
      (data) => {
        console.log("Exit Region");
      }
    )

  }
}
```

home.html

```
<div class="card-beacon" *ngIf="beacon_found">
</div>
```

The problem is that when I detect the beacon, the div is not being displayed. I read something about async databiding, but I have no idea how to do it.

Does anybody know how to solve it, please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I got it working using ChangeDetectorRef

```
import { Component, Input, ChangeDetectorRef } from '@angular/core';

export class HomePage {
  beacon_found: boolean;

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public events: Events, public cdr: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    events.subscribe('beacon:detected',(data) => {
      this.beacon_found = true;
      cdr.detectChanges();
    })

    events.subscribe('beacon:undetected',(data) => {
      this.beacon_found = false;
      cdr.detectChanges();
    })
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is where you should use an rxjs BehaviorSubject:

```
beaconFoundSubject : BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);
```

In your constructor (where NgZone may need to be injected and used to notify beaconFoundSubject):

```
constructor(private ngzone: NgZone) {

....

delegate.didEnterRegion()
.subscribe(
  (data) => {
    this.ngzone.run(() => this.beaconFoundSubject.next(true));
  }
)
```

And then in your template:

```
<div class="card-beacon" *ngIf="beaconFoundSubject | async">
</div>
```

Comment: Hello @Peter, I tried your code but it doesn't work. It only shows when I change tab and return.

Comment: Thanks for trying @Morris. Looked again in my project where I took this code from, and found that I also used ngzone, which is probably the reason you experience that the change is not picked up until you change tab and return.